# ggplot2: axis.line and panel.border have different width

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

In ggplot2, why `axis.line` and `panel.border` have different width even if they are explicitly set to same value? In the attached picture the width of `y` axis of first plot (black color) is more then `y` axis of second plot (red color). I want them to be equal width (overlapping at `y` axis). Code to reproduce:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
data(iris)
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width))+geom_point()
##set p1 axis.line size to 5
p1 <- p1+ theme(axis.line = element_line(color="black", size = 5))
##set panel.border size to 5
p2 <- p1+theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
               panel.border = element_rect(colour = "red", fill=NA, size=5))
## overlap margin for display
p1 <- p1+theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,0,1), "cm"))
p2 <- p2+theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-1.5,1,1,1), "cm"))
ggarrange(p1, p2, heights = c(1,1), ncol =1,nrow = 2, align = "v")
```

[image]